# Случайный класс при наведение

Tags: javascript, классы

Есть 5 классов со стилями
Как сделать чтобы при наведении к элементу добавлялся случайный класс?

```
html
<div class="block">
```

```
for (let i = 0; i <= square_nums; i++){
const square = document.createElement("div")
square.setAttribute("class", "square")
square.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    setColor(square)
    randomFg(square)
})
board.append(square)
square.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    removeColor(square)
})

on.addEventListener("click", () => {
    setColor(square)
    body.style.background = randomBg()
})

off.addEventListener("click", () => {
    removeColor(square)
    body.style.background = ""
    block.classList.remove(block.classList.contains("green")? "green": "red")
})
```

}

```
 const figures = ["triangle", 
     "hexagon", "close", "star", 
       "circle"]
        function randomFg(item){
      item.classList.add()
         let randomClass = ""
        for (let i = 0; i < 
      figures.length; i++){
    let rand = 
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 
     figures.length)
    randomClass += figures[rand]
    }
     return randomClass
    }

      console.log(randomFg())
```

Comment: Я знаю как добавлять классы но как сделать чтобы из 5 классов добвлялся 1 случайный?

Comment: Math.random() - генерация случайного числа. Имена классов можно поместить в массив, оттуда брать по случайному индексу..

Comment: Я так и сделал но в item.classList.add() < сюда как добавить? Мне пишет ошибку

Comment: код в студию! :)

Comment: Добавил код! :)

Comment: item.classList.add() - а где собственно класс, который должен добавляться?

Comment: вы код на телефоне что ли пишите, что он у вас так прекрасно отформатирован?

Comment: Вот у меня выводит ошибку когда туда добавляю класс

Comment: item.classList.add("first"); <<-- так добавляют. У Вас item чему равен? Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: а зачем цикл по всем классам? Надо добавить какой-то один класс?

Comment: Добавить 1 случайный класс из 5

Comment: и стоило бы html со стилями  приложить, иначе как работоспособность проверять?

Answer (score 0):

Так работает, класс в item добавляется.

```js
const figures = ["triangle",
  "hexagon", "close", "star",
  "circle"
]

function randomFg() {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() *
      figures.length)
      
  return figures[rand];
}

let randomClass = randomFg();
console.log(item.classList.value)
item.classList.add(randomClass);
console.log(item.classList.value);
```

```html
<div id = 'item' class="block">
```